# Refresh ListView after deletion

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onlongclicklistener

I checked a lot of stack overflow question, and none of them helped.
How to refresh my listView after deleting item with onLongClickListener?
As you'll see nor `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, nor `listView.invalidateViews()` don't work.

This is implementation with just necessary methods to figure out idea.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public FloatingActionButton fabAddWord;
public Toolbar toolbar;
public ListView listView;
private RjecnikCursorAdapter adapter;

private RjecnikDB dbRjecnik;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    fabAddWord = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAddWord);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    dbRjecnik = new RjecnikDB(this);
    db = dbRjecnik.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + RjecnikDB.TABLE;
    cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    adapter = new RjecnikCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            deleteOnLongClick(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_RIJEC)));

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.invalidateViews();

            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void deleteOnLongClick(String rijec) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbRjecnik.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(RjecnikDB.TABLE, RjecnikDB.COLUMN_RIJEC + " = ?", new String[] {rijec} );

    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    this.listView.invalidateViews();

    db.close();
}
```

CustomAdapter

```
public class RjecnikCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public RjecnikCursorAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_word, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView tvSingleLineWord = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSingleLineWord);

    // Extract properties from cursor
    String rijec = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_RIJEC));

    // Populate fields with extracted properties
    tvSingleLineWord.setText(rijec);
}
```

}

Comment: I belive you are just deleting from DB not from adapter?

Comment: When I go to another activity, and get back, deleted textView is gone. So, how should I delete from adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adapter have a data cache, so data in `ListView` will not change when data in database changed. You should change the cursor.

```
@Override
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    mIndexer.setCursor(cursor);
    super.changeCursor(cursor);
}
```

put code below to your `OnItemLongClickListener`

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
adapter.changeCurosr(cursor);
```

Comment: `db.rawQuery(query, null);` 
first param query should be `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME` ?

Comment: Yes, so you can set `String query = "SELECT * FROM " + RjecnikDB.TABLE;` to `final`

Comment: In the case of big database, will frequently querying affect speed?

Comment: knock-on certainty. I suggest that you don't use this approach. Split the database part and UI part, then  loaddata With the method of asynchronous.

Comment: By the way, you should load data from database asynchronous. If you have any other questions, send an email to me. zhenghuiy@gmail.com

Comment: Can you post here any tutorial about that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use just notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh your listView data, invalidateViews() will only redraw the visible items yet nothing on them has changed (changing font for example).

Note that is recommanded to run your notifyDataSetChanged() on UI thread.

**EDIT 2 :** you can use BaseAdapter instead of CursorAdapter like below

```
public class RjecnikCursorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> rjecnikList;


    public RjecnikCursorAdapter(Activity activity, List<String> rjecnikList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.rjecnikList = rjecnikList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rjecnikList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return rjecnikList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_word, null);

        TextView tvSingleLineWord = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSingleLineWord);

        tvSingleLineWord.setText(String.valueOf(rjecnikList.get(position)));


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

And in your activity :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public FloatingActionButton fabAddWord;
    public Toolbar toolbar;
    public ListView listView;
    public  List<String> mylist;
    private RjecnikCursorAdapter adapter;

    private RjecnikDB dbRjecnik;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        fabAddWord = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabAddWord);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        dbRjecnik = new RjecnikDB(this);
        db = dbRjecnik.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + RjecnikDB.TABLE;
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        mylist = new ArrayList<>();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

 do{
//change this with your column data
      String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data");

      mylist.add(data);

   }while(cursor.moveToNext());

}

cursor.close();
        adapter = new RjecnikCursorAdapter(this, mylist);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                deleteOnLongClick(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_RIJEC)));
                mylist.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.invalidateViews();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void deleteOnLongClick(String rijec) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbRjecnik.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(RjecnikDB.TABLE, RjecnikDB.COLUMN_RIJEC + " = ?", new String[] {rijec} );

        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.listView.invalidateViews();

        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: Still not working. I added `new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();`
and only after I go to another activity and get back, deleted textView is removed.

Comment: 1- please can you edit your post by adding your adapter code?  2- to run a code on UI thread you don't need to use another thread, just the runOnUiThrad

Comment: I don't have remove method for listView. Only few that actualy trying to remove view like `removeView, removeViewAt, removeFooterView` etc.
And all of them causes errors like `removeViewAt(int) is not supported in AdapterView`

Comment: Yes sorry i confused with List